# G-orbit in a Grassmann manifold

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a point the Grassmannian $Gr(r,\mathbb C^m)$. If the group $G$ acts on $Gr(r,\mathbb C^m)$. Why $G\cdot X\hookrightarrow \mathbb {CP}_m$?

Comment: What's $\mathbb P_m$?

Comment: the protective space

Comment: If $G$ acts transitively on the grassmanian,then $G\cdot X$ is the whole grassmanian, so are you asking why does the grassmanian $G(r,C^m)$ embed in $CP^m$? It doesn't.

Comment: ok maybe i have to cancel the condition of being  a transitive action.

Comment: It is still not true in general (as $G$ might act transitively....)

Comment: Well, there *are* groups which do act transitively on the grassmanian, so your edit does not help!

Comment: You are correct, my question is about Tits fibration. So I will rewrite my question carefully and post it again, thanks :)